# Is it possible to upload an FTP file using the InternetExplorer COM object?

Tags: internet-explorer, ftp

Is it possible to instantiate an IE COM object and use it to programmatically upload a file to an FTP site?

Comment: I don't believe IE supports that, if your after FTP functionality what language are you using?

Comment: It's for a scripting language called PowerScript (part of the PowerBuilder IDE).  The reason I'd like to use the IE COM object is because it should be compatible (hopefully) with all versions of windows.  The COM object we were using before does not work with Windows 7.

Comment: Aside from using a 3rd party component (chilkat have a free one) there is the FTP command line utility

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure but I don't think there's an easy way to accomplish this - but then the IE COM object has tons of functions....  Assuming you're looking for a solution that's guaranteed to be available on Windows computers, a simpler route would be to use [wininet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384180%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  That API is relatively simple to use, has explicit support for ftp and is well documented on MSDN and other places.